# Html.Checkboxfor disabled - not binding properly on page

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkboxfor

I have a HTML markup of my page like this :

```
<div class="form-group m-b-30">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.RememberMe)
            <label for="checkbox5">Remember me</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in my viewmodel:

```
public bool RememberMe {get;set;}
```

but the checkbox is not clickable at all....

What am I doing wrong?

Hi @StephenMuecke, this is the generated HTML with the above Html.CheckBoxFor:

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                                                <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The RememberMe field is required." id="checkbox5" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false">
                                                <label for="checkbox5">
                                                    Remember me
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
```

And this is the included picture of the page how it looks like:

[image]

```
.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  background-color: #458bc4;
  border-color: #458bc4; }
.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  color: #ffffff; }
```

And the checkbox class:

```
.checkbox {
  padding-left: 20px; }
  .checkbox label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal; }
```

Comment: Guys, apparently class "checkbox" is doing something wrong, but if I remove it it takes away the design of my checkbox... Not sure what to do ?

Comment: The checkbox it self is, but not the label which is associated with a control named `checkbox5` (which I assume does not exist). Use `@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.RememberMe)`

Comment: It has something to do with those css classes

Comment: Are you using a plugin to style you checkbox? And what is the css definition for `class="checkbox checkbox-primary"`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke by doing the first solution like u noted it gives me double checkbox with a double label "Remember me"

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes I'm using bootstrap framework to style it

Comment: by using a simple: <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox5" /> it works...

Comment: Then you need to show the relevant details - no doubt its because the plugin is hiding the original checkbox and replacing it with its own html for styling the appearance. Add the details of the plugin, and the full html that is being generated by your code (and an image would help)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added more details in my original question as you requested =)

Comment: The issue is with the css selectors - `.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {` means the `<label>` element immediately following a `<input type="checkbox" .. />` element which does not exist because the `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` method generates a hidden input in between them

Comment: @StephenMuecke what should I do, is there any way I could combine these two ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134278/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user987).